# Any way to recover Yosemite download from AppStore?

Tags: macos, mac-appstore

When I opened the folder of previously paid-for apps on the AppStore in order to download Yosemite, I inadvertently clicked the "X" mark next to the "Download" button. This removed Yosemite from the list. Any way to get it back?

Answer (score 1):

In the App Store, Store => View my Account, In the Account Information window, the item Hidden Items => Hidden Purchases: Unhide any hidden, redownloadable Purchases.

Click Manage, You'll see a list hidden purchases which you can UNHIDE.

Comment: Thanks! By going into my account on the AppStore, I was indeed able to unhide the app, then download it.

Comment: While checking the answer I was surprised at the number of things I have hidden.

Answer (score -1):

From what I can tell, no.

You can find someone with an Apple ID who has downloaded it though, sign in with their credentials, and redownload it that.